# MySQL in Java - INSERT and DELETE statements not working properly

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller

- There are two tables `chat_users` and `chat_lines`.
- Insert and Select work well on `chat_user`
- Update on `chat_user` is **not working**
- Insert into `chat_lines` **doesn't work** either

Source listing for **chat_user_model.java**

```
package model;

import Beans.ChatLineBeans;
import Beans.ChatUserBeans;
import java.security.Timestamp;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class chat_user_model extends DBConnection  {

public static void add_User(ChatUserBeans user ) throws ClassNotFoundException  {

        try {

            Connection conn = createConnection();
            PreparedStatement s;
            s = conn.prepareStatement (
               "INSERT INTO chat_users (name, gravatar) VALUES(?,?)");
             s.setString (1,user.getuserName());
             s.setString (2, user.getgravatar());
             int count = s.executeUpdate ();
             s.close ();
              conn.close();
             //System.out.println (count + " rows were inserted");

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(chat_user_model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

    }
public static  ChatUserBeans find_user(String name ) {
    ChatUserBeans user=new ChatUserBeans();
        try {
            Connection con = createConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select  * from chat_users where name=? ");
            stmt.setString(1, name);
            ResultSet result= stmt.executeQuery();
            while(result.next())
            {
              user.setuserName(result.getString("name"));
              user.setgravatar(result.getString("gravatar"));
            }
            stmt.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(chat_user_model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    return user ;

}
public static void add_line(ChatLineBeans line ) throws ClassNotFoundException  {

        try {

            Connection conn = createConnection();
            PreparedStatement s;
            s = conn.prepareStatement (
               "INSERT INTO chat_lins (aurther, gravatar,text) VALUES(?,?,?)");
             s.setString (1,line.getauther());
             s.setString (2, line.getgravatar());
             s.setString (3, line.gettext());
             int count = s.executeUpdate ();
             s.close ();
             conn.close();

             //System.out.println (count + " rows were inserted");

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(chat_user_model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


    }

public static void delete_User(String name ) throws ClassNotFoundException  {

        try {
            Connection conn = createConnection();
            PreparedStatement s;
            s = conn.prepareStatement (
               "DLETE FROM chat_users WHERE name=?");
             s.setString (1,name);
             int count = s.executeUpdate ();
             s.close ();
              conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(chat_user_model.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



    }
}
```

and the connection file is

```
    package model;


    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DBConnection {
        private static String hostName = "localhost";
        private static String port = "3306";
        private static String dbName ="120623085702";
        private static String userName = "root";
        private static String password="";
        public static Connection createConnection(){
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostName + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;
                System.out.println(url);
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
                return con;

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Any suggestion about how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not working means what? Did they throw any errors? Please post the error stack thrown.

Comment: no error but no modification in the database :(

Comment: Did you try debugging the value of `count`. It actually informs the number of rows affected. `0` means no rows affected for the input query parameters.

Comment: I would double check your code and your JDBC string you are using for a connection in createConnection, make sure you are specifying the default database as well. I would also make sure whatever database account you are using can write to the tables in question.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon OP said insert is working for `chat_user` table.

Comment: @NONA : Instead of `Logger.getLogger(` use `System.out.println("Exception" +ex)` and let me know what you get...

Comment: @NONA `ex.printStackTrace()` would be better.

Comment: Maybe it's not in auto-commit mode, so your transactions aren't completing?

Comment: You also should have your connection.close() and preparedStatement.close() calls inside of a finally block.  When an exception is getting thrown in your code you are almost certainly leaking connections to your DB and at some point your DB will probably stop handing new ones out.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled DELETE in your query. That would be the cause of the delete statement not working. The reason you're not seeing an error might be that your logging's not set up correctly. If that's the case, anything could be going wrong with the insert statement, and you wouldn't know what it was (e.g. columns/tables missing, accidentally inserting null into a non-nullable column). Try not catching those SQLExceptions, and see if you see any errors then.